# iOS read characteristics in core bluetooth returns junk value

Tags: ios, cordova-plugins, core-bluetooth

I am using Cordova central able plugin to connect to a bluetooth device from iOS. Objective here is to write the data to the bluetooth device and read the response for the same. I could able to write the data without any errors and when i am trying to read the data from the same characteristics response is some junk value instead.

I have already searched in all possible sites for the answers with no luck. Hope i can get some solution plz.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Junk values", can you be more specific about that? How do you write, how do you read?

Comment: I am writing the values using the [peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:aChar type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse]; method and reading with the [peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic];. But irrespective of what data i am trying to write on the device it is not giving the correct response.

Comment: does it have something to do with MFi certified. The device which i am trying to connect is SPP device. Do i need add the device in the MFi program for me to write and read from the device. I could able to connect successfully to the device though

Comment: What do you compare? a NSData object? If it's BLE, it doesn't need MFi.

Comment: Yes it's NSData object. The requirement is like i write data to the SPP device and this should respond me with model number of the SPP device. The same workflow works fine in android but in iOS when i am doing the same thing it just responds me with the same value irrespective of what value i write to the characteristic